# How does AppDelegate become UIApplication's delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, appdelegate, swift-protocols

I'm just trying to understand the general architecture of `UIApplication`.  My understanding of using a delegate works something like following:

```swift
protocol MyDelegate {
    func someProtocolMethod()
}

class SomeClass {

    var delegate: MyDelegate!

    init(){
    }

    func someClassMethod(){
        self.delegate.someProtocolMethod() 
    }
}

class ClassConformingToDelegate: NSObject, MyDelegate {

    let someClass: SomeClass

    override init(){
        someClass = SomeClass()
        super.init()
        someClass.delegate = self // self has to be assigned so that SomeClass's delegate property knows what the conforming class is
    }        

    func someProtocolMethod(){}
}
```

In a similar fashion, `AppDelegate` conforms to `UIApplicationDelegate` by having a number of protocol methods implemented.

```swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
}
```

`UIApplication` declares the delegate as following in its class:

```swift
unowned(unsafe) var delegate: UIApplicationDelegate?
```

But, in order for this delegate to know that `AppDelegate.swift` is the true delegate, `UIApplication` has to be instantiated and `AppDelegate.swift` be assigned to the instance, similar to the example above.  So something like the following should happen within `AppDelegate.swift`:

```swift
let application = UIApplication()
application.delegate = self
```

But, how is this step omitted and `AppDelegate` still works?

Comment: "how is this step omitted" It's not omitted. It's somewhere in the depths of UIKit, and probably not written in Swift. It won't be setting `delegate` to `self`, but to your app delegate class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question varies a little depending on which version of Xcode/Swift/iOS you are talking about, but the essential process is the same.

If you create a project in Xcode that uses the UIKit AppDelegate lifecycle then you will see the line `@main` at the start of the `AppDelegate.swift` file.

This tells the compiler that this file contains the `UIApplicationDelegate` implementation.  The compiler then synthesises a `main` function for you that performs all of the required setup, including creating an instance of the `AppDelegate` and assigning it to the `UIApplication` instance.

In earlier versions of Swift you would see `@UIApplicationMain` that does essentially the same thing.

You can omit the `@main`/`@UIApplicationMain` and create your own main that does all of the required work, but this generally isn't required.

With SwiftUI you now have the option of using SwiftUI lifecycle rather than UIKit lifecycle when you create the project.  In this case you have an `App` struct.  This file still contains the `@main` and is used to launch your app's view hierarchy.

Comment: Ah so that's how the @main attribute works as an entry point.  I'm assuming `AppDelegate` has an extension with a static `main()` function somewhere that executes what you mentioned above?

Comment: Not quite.  If the `main` function was an extension of the AppDelegate then the system would still need to somehow know the name of the AppDelegate class.  `main` is just a global function that is called just like `main` is automatically called in a standard C program.  The compiler determines the name of the App Delegate class by examining the file with the `@main` directive and uses that to write the `main` function.